# Simple debug logging

Tags: c++, beginner

I'm new to C++, and I wanted to add a way to log in a fancy way. As such, I created a small bit of code to do so, but I'm wondering how I can improve my code, especially the fact that `DebugColors` consists of two files, and regarding my use of templates, as I don't think the `adder` method(s) of the Debug struct is the best way to concatenate strings.

Additionally, I'm unsure if I should be using a struct in order to contain the methods, or if I should use a namespace for it, as I only want to be able to access the public methods from outside the struct.

**DebugColors.hpp**

```
#ifndef DEBUG_COLORS
#define DEBUG_COLORS

#include <string>

namespace DebugColors {
    extern std::string reset;
    extern std::string red;
    extern std::string green;
    extern std::string yellow;
    extern std::string blue;
}

#endif
```

**DebugColors.cpp**

```cpp
#include "DebugColors.hpp"

namespace DebugColors {
    std::string reset = "\x1b[0m";
    std::string red = "\x1b[31m";
    std::string green = "\x1b[32m";
    std::string yellow = "\x1b[33m";
    std::string blue = "\x1b[34m";
}
```

**Debug.hpp**

````
#ifndef DEBUG_HPP
#define DEBUG_HPP

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "DebugColors.hpp"

struct Debug {
    private:
        template<typename T>
        static T adder(T v) {
            return v;
        }

        template<typename T, typename ...Args>
        static T adder(T first, Args ...args) {
            return first + " " + adder<std::string>(args...);
        }

        template<typename ...T>
        static void LogMessage(T&... args) {
            std::string message = adder<std::string>(args...);
            
            std::cout << message << std::endl;
        }
    public:
    template<typename ...T>
        static void Log(T&... args) {
            LogMessage(args...);
        }

        template<typename ...T>
        static void Info(T&... args) {
            LogMessage(DebugColors::blue, "[INFO]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
        }

        template<typename ...T>
        static void Warning(T&... args) {
            LogMessage(DebugColors::yellow, "[WARN]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
        }
        
        template<typename ...T>
        static void Error(T&... args) {
            LogMessage(DebugColors::red, "[ERROR]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
        }

        template<typename ...T>
        static void Success(T&... args) {
            LogMessage(DebugColors::green, "[SUCCESS]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
        }
};

#endif
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `namespaces`

We can put everything into a `namespace` which would enable us to use `using`.

Consider this example,

```cpp
using Debug::Log; //Error if it's a static member function
                  // Error msg: error: ‘Debug’ is not a namespace or unscoped enum

namespace Debug{
   Type Func(){ ... };
}

using Debug::Func; // No error

Func(); // Calls `Debug::Func`
```

Since, `Log`, `Info`, `Error`, `Warning` and `Success` are just standalone utility functions. I see no reason to put them in a class.

We can put private functions into a different `namespace` say `impl`, a namespace which would contain private functions of `Debug` class.

```
namespace impl{
  std::string add(...) {...}
  void LogMessage(...) {...}
}

namespace Debug{
  void Log(...) { impl::LogMessage(...) }
  void Info(...) { impl::LogMessage(...) }
  void Error(...) { impl::LogMessage(...) }
}
```

### Use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to print `int`s and `float`s

Create a `to_str` function which would call `std::string`. Why this is necessary is explained in the below paragraphs.

```
namespace impl {

template<typename T>
std::string to_str(const T& val){
    return std::to_string(val);
}

std::string to_str(const std::string& val){
    return val;
}

std::string to_str(const char * str){
    return std::string(str);
}

} // namespace impl
```

### [Fold Expression since C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)

We can leverage fold expression when working with variadic functions. We can rewrite the `adder` as such.

```
namespace impl{

template <typename... Args>
std::string adder(Args... args) {
  return ((to_str(args) + " ") + ...);
}

}
```

### [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842571/is-a-forwarding-reference-still-an-rvalue-reference-or-not)

Your current implementation we can only use *lvalues* with functions. Using forwarding reference we can pass both *lvalues* and *rvalues*.

```
namespace Debug{

template <typename... T>
void Log(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(args...);
}
// Similarly for other functions too.
}
```

---

### Full code

`Debug.hpp`

```
#ifndef DEBUG_HPP
#define DEBUG_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "DebugColors.h"

namespace impl {

template<typename T>
std::string to_str(const T& val){
    return std::to_string(val);
}

std::string to_str(const std::string& val){
    return val;
}

std::string to_str(const char * str){
    return std::string(str);
}

template <typename... Args>
std::string adder(Args&&... args) {
  return ((to_str(args) + " ") + ...);
}

template <typename... T>
void LogMessage(T&&... args) {
  std::string message = adder(args...);

  std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
}  // namespace impl

namespace Debug {
template <typename... T>
void Log(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(args...);
}

template <typename... T>
void Info(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(DebugColors::blue, "[INFO]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
}

template <typename... T>
void Warning(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(DebugColors::yellow, "[WARN]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
}

template <typename... T>
void Error(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(DebugColors::red, "[ERROR]", args..., DebugColors::reset);
}

template <typename... T>
void Success(T&&... args) {
  impl::LogMessage(DebugColors::green, "[SUCCESS]", args...,
                   DebugColors::reset);
}

}  // namespace Debug

#endif
```

---

`test.cpp`

```
include "Debug.hpp"

using Debug::Error;
int main(){
  int t = 10;
  Error("Danger", 20, t, 3.14);
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

You can use [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) for formatting your code files.

Terminal command:

```
clang-format -style=Google -i files
```

Comment: Good review!  What do you think about also mentioning `std::string_view` for the color codes?

Comment: @Edward I would suggest that too.  But this rewritten code would unnecessarily convert it to `string` each time.  It also converts `const char*`.

Comment: @Ch3steR instead of `to_str` call it `wrap` or something that does not imply a specific return type.  Use `string_view` as returns for `const char*` and `string_view` itself, as well as `string` so you don't have to copy it.  But keep `string` return for numbers and such where it allocates memory as part of the conversion.

Comment: @Edward Thank you. Yes `string_view` is much better.

Comment: @JDługosz Yes agreed, `to_str` is unnecessarily creating copies. I'm not near my laptop. Can you add it an answer since it's very good suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

### Everything @Ch3steR said

### Const Correctness

You don't want some other developer breaking your code by accidentally changing the value of your color variables. So you should make them costant (that will make sure the compiler does not allow any alterations:

```
namespace DebugColors {
    extern std::string const reset;
    extern std::string const red;
    extern std::string const green;
    extern std::string const yellow;
    extern std::string const blue;
}
```

You can also use `std::string` literals (rather than C-String literals that call the constructor).

```
namespace DebugColors {

    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::string const reset  = "\x1b[0m"s;   // Notice the s
    std::string const red    = "\x1b[31m"s;
    std::string const green  = "\x1b[32m"s;
    std::string const yellow = "\x1b[33m"s;
    std::string const blue   = "\x1b[34m"s;
}
```